# music player sayonara

Tags: music

I install sayonara in ubuntu 20.04 lts and it's show like

```
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucioc/sayonara/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucioc/sayonara/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucioc/sayonara/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

what can i do? I'm new to Ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 1):

Debian package for Ubuntu 20.04 is not available via repository as of now.   You can install sayonara using snap. Open terminal and execute below command to install it via snap.

```
sudo snap install sayonara
```

Answer (score 1):

The developer developed the software at a certain time when there was no Ubuntu 20.04. After every new release, the developer has to update his software for the new released Ubuntu 20.04 lts. If he fails to do this, then the error shown to you occurs.

Generally you cannot install that app on the unsupported versions. That app is just not supported. You cannot really do anything unless the developer releases an update for your Ubuntu version.

However there is a beta for your Ubuntu version.
Look [here.](https://launchpad.net/%7Elucioc/+archive/ubuntu/sayonara-experimental)

To install type the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:lucioc/sayonara
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lucioc/sayonara-experimental 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install sayonara
```

Comment: I have added old PPA removal to your instruction to make it more reproducible.